# Powershell: Get VM Properties

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I Created a VM and I want to export its properties in a CSV file. 
what I tried does not give me the IPAddress, SwitchName, Macaddress.

```
$Data = @();
$VMs = Get-VM $VMName;
foreach($VM in $VMs){
$VMCustom = New-Object System.Object;
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name VMName -Value $VM.VMName;
# Get-VMNetworkAdapter -VMName $VMName | Select -expand IPAddresses
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $VM.guest.IPAddresses;
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name SwitchName -Value $VM.MacAddress;
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $VM.State;
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Generation -Value $VM.Generation;
$VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name SwitchName -Value $VM.SwitchName;

$Data += $VMCustom;
} 

$Data | Export-CSV "C:\VM.csv" -Delimiter ";";
```

Question: Is the Ipaddress, the IPaddress of the VM or the IPaddress of the Hyper-V?

That would be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: on VMware, IPAddress is an Array with IPV4 and IPV6 Addresses - so if this is the case with HyperV,  try `$vm.Guest.IPAddress[0]`

Comment: Error: it is impossible to add index on a NULL-Array !!

Comment: Do `$VM.IPAddresses` and show us the results

Comment: Have a look at Get-VMNetworkAdapter it will return the MacAddress, SwitchName and IPAddresses

Comment: @Oggew: I do not know how to export them in CSV. I have tried: Get-VM $VMName| Select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters | Select VMName, SwitchName, IPAddress, Macaddress, Status | Export-Csv "C:\VM.csv" -Delimiter ";" and works. but I want to use foreach loop.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hyper-v but regarding your comment Try this: `Get-VMNetworkAdapter  -VM $VMName | Select VMName, SwitchName, IPAddress, Macaddress, Status  | Export-Csv "C:\VM.csv"`

Comment: @Avshalom: I want to use foreach loop. by your command or the command I have written to Oggew, the IPaddress is still empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$Data = @()

$VMs = "Server-001","Server-002","Server-003"

foreach($VM in $VMs)
{
    $VMInfo = Get-VM -Name $VM
    $VMNetwork = $VMInfo | Get-VMNetworkAdapter

    $VMCustom = New-Object System.Object
    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name VMName -Value $VMInfo.VMName
    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Status -Value $VMInfo.Status
    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Generation -Value $VMInfo.Generation

    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $VMNetwork.IPAddresses[0]
    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name MacAddress -Value $VMNetwork.MacAddress
    $VMCustom | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name SwitchName -Value $VMNetwork.SwitchName

    $Data += $VMCustom
} 

$Data | Export-CSV "C:\VM.csv" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks. Everything works except IPaddress which is still empty. does it have any relationship if the IP is static or Dynamic? is it possible to add a column to check if the IP is static or dynamic?

Comment: If you run this, does it return anything?$VMInfo = Get-VM -Name "Server-001";$VMNetwork = $VMInfo | Get-VMNetworkAdapter;$VMNetwork.IPAddresses

Comment: It is interesting. from yesterday till Today I have changed nothing, but today it shows the IP address. Great. Thanks.